# character visible but not selectable/highlightable

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, forms

We have a website built in wordpress using WP forms.

On any page where a contact form appears there is a random _ character on the top left. This character can't be highlighted, can't be selected and doesn't appear in the DOM.

It doesn't appear to be part of any :before, :after css rules which was my first guess.

The anomaly can be found here: https://www.lazyduck.co.uk/contact-us/

Does anyone have any suggestions how to find where it came from, and why we can't inspect it?

[image: example]

Comment: Post something for code. This is like a mechanic trying to fix a noise that's appears to be coming from the engine and over the telephone; and sound travels. Have a look at your HTML source and your developer console, that should help.

Comment: provide link to website

Comment: Added a link to the page where it shows. none of this is custom code we've written but i'll look through the theme templates and see what I can find.

Comment: It isn't actually a character (despite it looking like an underscore) which is why you cannot select or highlight it, it seems to be border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `:before` CSS attribute on the element `<li class="choice-1 depth-1">`.  It looks like it's used for styling, however in the case of this page obviously it's not working very well.

If the problem only exists on the page you linked to, you can disable the box with the following CSS:

```
.page-id-168 .post-content ul > li:before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to find a way to disable that CSS across the whole site.

**Edit** You can inspect the element by right-clicking on it and choosing `Inspect` in Chrome or `Inspect Element` in FireFox.